# how I can update a field value in firestore using PATCH request (in R) and keep the others?

Tags: r, firebase, http, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying data in Firestore and I would like to update a specific value in a table using the PATCH request in **R**, but the code delete ALL the documents and rewrite just with the field I want to update, anyone knows why this happens?

My code is the following:

```
sign.in <- function(email, password, api_key) {
  library(jsonlite)
  library(httr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(lubridate)
  #https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/#section-sign-in-email-password
  r <- POST(paste0("https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=", api_key),
            add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json"),
            body = toJSON(list(email = email, password = password, returnSecureToken = TRUE),auto_unbox=TRUE))
  return(content(r))
}


update_document <- function(db_endpoint, auth_token, document_path, update_data) {
  url <- sprintf("https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/%s", document_path)
  r <- PATCH(
    url,
    add_headers("Content-Type" = "application/json", "Authorization" = paste("Bearer", auth_token)),
    body = toJSON(update_data, auto_unbox = TRUE)
  )
  return(content(r))
}

my_auth_info <- sign.in(
  "mimail@company.com",
  "mypassword",
  "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
)

update_data <- list(
  fields = list(
    source = list(stringValue = "facebook")
  )
)

#document path
document_path <- "projects/company/databases/(default)/documents//driver_lead/leads/prospects/prospectnamefield"

update_document(
  db_endpoint = "projects/company/databases/(default)/documents",
  auth_token = my_auth_info$idToken,
  document_path = document_path,
  update_data = update_data
)
```